# Charles Rambo GRE Practice Book Test 2 #25

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

At a particular university, 200 students are registered as math majors.  There are:
100 taking real analysis
50 taking linear algebra
90 taking abstract algebra
40 taking real analysis and linear algebra
75 taking real analysis and abstract algebra 
15 taking linear algebra and abstract algebra and
3 taking all three courses

How many math majors are taking none of the 3 courses?

My question is: is this question not nonsensical?  How can 50 be taking linear but yet 15 are in linear and abstract and 40 are in linear and real analysis with only 3 overlapping?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. Yes it is nonsensical. You are right. They just wanted to check if you can find $|A \cup B \cup C | $ from the intersections and failed to check if the numbers actually made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a mistake. I just noticed this post and changed the manuscript. Thank you for your help! If anybody finds any other errors, please email me.

Charles Rambo

[image]